# How to solve Argument K missing by default error

Tags: r

I have a function below and I have K to be a range of values and want to set lambda =2.

When I run the code I get an error in R- argument k is missing with no default.

What am I doing wrong?

```
lnmp <- function(mu, k) {
  n <- length(k)
  -n*mu + log(mu)*sum(k) - sum(lfactorial(k))
}

k<-c(5,12,10,22,45,67,39,28,45,53,45,41,4,lamhda=2)
lnmp(k)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set your function `lnmp` with two inputs, `mu` and `k`. However, you only passed one. The important thing is that ***it doesn't matter what the argument you passed is named***, it's going to be the first one. If you name it `dog`, it's still going to be treated as `mu` inside the function. Since you didn't pass a second argument, `k` is not defined (it has no value). Therefore, what you have to do is **pass both arguments when you call the function** (therefore, `lnmp(first, second)` or `lnmp(mu, k)`).